# Multiple arguments for "face" in element_text

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am adding aesthetics to a plot in R using themes in ggplot2.  I would like to make the x axis text both bold and italic.

I know I can use:

```
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face ="bold"))
```

to make the axis text bold and:

```
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face ="italic"))
```

to make it italic.

But how would I make it both bold and italic?

None of these do the job

```
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face ="italic", "bold"))
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face =c("bold", "italic")))
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", face = "italic"))
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold" & "italic"))
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: use `face = "bold.italic"` and have a look at the [documentation](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/3364_d1a578f521174152b46b19d0c83cbe7e.html)

Comment: Thanks @Jimbou I've been using [this page]http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/themes.html) for reference.  It doesn't detail this argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`?element_text` says the following are the options (have you tried  `face ="bold.italic"`?) :

> **face**    font face ("plain", "italic", "bold", "bold.italic")

Comment: No I had not tried that, and thank you for reminding me of help. Works a treat - I feel like an idiot.